# Not match empty string

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression like this 'a?b?'. It will match either 'a', 'b', or 'ab'. The problem is that it will also match '' (empty string). How do I change it so that it will only match the above 3 cases and not empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern with a character set of both letters to force the inclusion of one of them:

```
(?=[ab])a?b?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ehy74D/1